# Не работает push_back() в лямбде

Tags: c++

Почему не работает `a.push_back(b)` в лямбде?

```
list<double> temp;
list<double> result = std::accumulate( vec.begin(), vec.end(), temp,
                                    [](const std::list<double>& a, double b) {
                                        return b<2.0 ? a.push_back(b): a ;
                                });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В ваше лямба-выражение передается ссылка на *константный объект*, а вы пытаетесь изменить его внутренее состояние посредством `push_back`, для решения вашей проблемы достаточно убрать модификатор `const`:

```
[](std::list<double>& a, double b)
```

---

У вас также имеется еще одна ошибка, связанная с возвращаемым значением в лямбе. Она ожидает получить на выходе экземпляр типа `list<double>` (т.е. `decltype(temp)`), а у вас одним из вариантов возвращаемого значения является тип `void` (результат `a.push_back(b)`).

Таким образом, рабочий вариант:

```
list<double> result = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), temp,
    [](std::list<double>& a, double b)
    {
        if (b < 2.0)
            a.push_back(b);
        return a;
    }
);
```